# Replacing spaces in a variable with hyphen using AngularJs

Tags: angularjs

Am trying to replace all the spaces in a message  variable with hyphen.
 For instance from   **"here is my message to be"** to **"here-is-my-message-to-be"**

can someone help me

```
 .controller('postNotif',
                ['$scope', '$http', '$rootScope', function ($scope, $http, $rootScope) {
                        $rootScope.modal = [];
                        $rootScope.notification = {

                            messages: "here is my message to be",

                         link: timing
                        };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `replace` function:

```
message.replace(/\s/g, "-");
```

Answer (score 1):

use this method on ur string variable

```
.replace(/ /g, "-");
```